# What does it mean if all the derivatives of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal around a point?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I've been talking to a friend and he suddenly shows up with this. He says it just popped out in his mind and we've been discussing it for some time (we are both amateurs at math, so if anything is wrong or dumb here, i apologize in advance).

Let be $f(x)$ and $g(x) $ are functions infinitely differentiable (you can derivate them forever. ie: $e^x$), and $$H(x) = \{{f(x),\ if\ x<a \\ g(x),\ if\ x\ge a}$$
If $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} {f^{(n)}(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to a} {g^{(n)}(x)}, \forall {x \in \Bbb{N}}$$
His intuition says it mean that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same function around $a$.

(yeah, i forgot to write this down, but $H(x)$ is continuous, that is, $f(a) = g(a)$)

Any opinions?

Comment: How about $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=-x^2$?

Comment: All their derivatives agree at $0$ and in fact they are $0$

Comment: Their second derivatives are different

Comment: What do you mean by *are the same function around $a$* ?

Comment: I guess i mean something like identically equal, but it started to get a bit phlosophical. I think you could say that they have the same definition, at least around a

Comment: Like, H(x) has a "smooth" definition change around a, you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac1{x^2}}, \text{ if $x>0$} \\ 0, \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Verify that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$. However, $f$ is not the zero function in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $|x|$ function. Both $f(x) $ and $g(x)$  have different first derivatives.